# Вызвано исключение прав доступа MS Visual Studio

Tags: c++

```
class Person {

public:
    char* name;

    Person(const char* name1) {
        strcpy(name, name1);
        cout << name << endl;
    }
};
```

Вот вызывающий код:

```
Person* name = new Person("Check");
```

Есть такой код. Понимаю что лучше не использовать char* а использовать string, и не использовать strcpy, но такое условие задания. Почему в том же CLion компилируется, а тут выводит:

```
Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00007FFE2EA3D1CD (ucrtbased.dll) в Lab1.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0x0000000000000000.
```

Comment: А вызывающий код где? Память выделена вообще?

Comment: Добавил вызывающий код

Comment: Надо же память выделить, чтобы было куда копировать.

Comment: А можете подсказать где ее выделить в моем коде

Comment: Перед копированием, например.

Comment: new char(sizeof(name1)) подойдет?

Comment: Нет, не подойдет, рекомендую почитать самую базу по работе с динамической памятью.

Comment: Поскольку вероятно в классе `Person` будет несколько текстовых полей, чтобы не повторять код можете написать свою мини-версию класса `string`, где инкапсулировать владение памятью под строку.

Comment: Научитесь различать ошибки компиляции и ошибки времени исполнения. У вас в программе вторая, и Visual Studio тут ни при чём.

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку вероятно в классе `Person` будет несколько текстовых полей, чтобы не повторять код можете написать свою мини-версию класса `string`, где инкапсулировать владение памятью под строку.
Вряд ли вам нужно будет много операций с такими строками - создание, присвоение, сравнение. Ну и нужно будет соблюсти [правило трёх](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%82%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85_(C%2B%2B))
Конкретно по операции из вопроса алгоритм действий такой:

- узнать длину входной строки (через `strlen`)
- выделить память под строку
- скопировать данные из входящей строки в свой буфер
- в деструкторе класса освободить память. (или вместо простого указателя использовать `std::unique_ptr<>`)
  Как-то так:

```
class Person {
private:
   char* name_ = nullptr;
public:
   Person(const char* name1) 
   {    
        if(!name1)  // проверка на нулевой указатель
           return;
        size_t length = strlen(name1);
        if(!length)  // проверка на нулевую длину строки
           return;
        name_ = new char[length+1];
        strcpy(name_, name1);
        cout << name_ << endl;
   }
   ~Person()
   {
      delete[] name_;
   }
};
```

Comment: Раз уж решили написать код за ТС, стоит добавить проверку приходящего указателя.

Comment: Правило трёх устарело, теперь требуется правило пяти

Comment: @PavelMayorov Знаю. Надеялся что автор хотя бы начнет читать про правило трёх и дочитает что уже нужно выполнять правило пяти. :)